# How to deal with error in minimalist example for iterators in HWUT

Tags: c, unit-testing, hwut

I am trying to run the documentation minimalist iterator example using the HWUT project, but in am getting the following errors.

```
C:\hwut\demo\c\iterator\TEST>hwut gen test-it.c
Error: maker '<<hwut-file: ...>>' is ignored since version 0.20.4.
Error: use '-o file-stem' on command line instead.
Error: missing closing '|' for range. found ':'
```

It is the code from the example:

```
#if 0
<<hwut-iterator:  myIterator>>
<<hwut-file:      myIterator>>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdint.h>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int Case;    int x;    int y;
    0;  |1:9:2|;  |1:9:2|;
    1; |0:10:2|;   |0:10|;
------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif

#include "hwut_unit.h"
#include "myIterator.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    myIterator_t it;

hwut_info("Check product of even and odd;");

myIterator_init(&it);

while( myIterator_next(&it) ) {
    if( it->Case == 0 ) {
       // Odd x Odd == Odd
       assert( my_product(it->x, it->y) % 2 != 0 );
    } else if( it->Case == 0 ) {
       // Even x Anything == Even
       assert( my_product(it->x, it->y) % 2 == 0 );
       assert( my_product(it->y, it->x) % 2 == 0 );
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what the problem is?
And is this project still supported? Otherwise, can someone recommend me a similar project with a bigger support?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The HWUT source code distribution contains unit test examples in 
the test on itself. You find the minimalist iterator example in the 
source tree of HWUT as shown below:

Directory:

```
     $HWUT_PATH/hwut/code_generation/generator/TEST
```

File:

```
     total.c
```

That is, the following demonstrates all syntax used to define generators:

```
#if 0 
<<hwut-iterator:  myGen1>> 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdint.h>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int x;    float y;   char* str;       uint32_t array;  float farray;

## Plain constants
        1;        2.0;         "a";        { 1, 2, 3, 4};     {1.0,1.1};
        2;        2.1;         "b";           { 1, 2, 3};     {2.0,1.2};
        3;        2.2;         "c";              { 1, 2};     {3.0,1.3};
        4;        2.3;         "d";                 { 1};     {4.0,1.4};

------------------------------------------------------------------------

<<hwut-iterator: myGen2>> 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdint.h>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int x;    float y;   char* str;       uint32_t array;  float farray;

## Selections
   [0, 1];        2.4;         "e";              { 1, 2};               {1.5};
        5; [7.1, 7.2];         "f";           { 1, 2, 3};               {1.5};
        6;        2.5;  ["X", "Y"];        { 1, 2, 3, 4};               {1.5};
        7;        2.6;         "i";     [{5, 6}, {7, 8}];               {1.5};
        8;        2.7;         "j";                 { 1};  [{6.0,6.1}, {7.0,7.1}];

------------------------------------------------------------------------

<<hwut-iterator: myGen3>> 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdint.h>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
        int x;                  float y;   
## Ranges
        |0:5|;                     -2.0; 
|5:10| step 2;                     -1.0;
           11;                |0.0:5.0|;
           12;       |5.0:7.0| step 0.5;

------------------------------------------------------------------------

<<hwut-iterator: myGen4>> 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <stdint.h>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
        int x;                        float y;   

## Focus Ranges                 
      1000;                             |x-1:x+1|;
       100;                             |x-3:x+3|;
        99;                                 |x:x|;
        10;              |x-0.5:x+1.25| step 0.25;
         0;      |x-3:x+1.5| in |-1.5:2| step 1.5;
------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

A usual test becomes something like:

```
#include <hwut_unit.h>

void              
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    hwut_info("This is a simple test;");

    myGen4_t       it;
    classUnderTest obj;

    myGen4_init(&it);

    while( myGen4_next(&it) ) {
        setup(&obj, &it);

        obj.memberFunction(it->some_arg, it->another_arg);

        check(&obj, it->some_parameters);
    }
}
```

And, yes the project is still active.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.